# How to change Windows phone listbox fill direction

Tags: listbox, windows-phone

I want to change the listbox fill direction from the bottom to top. In case there is just one item in the listbox, it is at the bottom of the listbox as default. if I add more items, how to make the new item be above the old item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be done before you bind your data to the listbox control. Add the new item to the to top of the list(data source) and then bind it with the control.

Comment: but if there is just one item in the list box, it will appear in the top of the listbox, isn't so?

Comment: I want to make item at the bottom of the listbox if there is just one item.

Comment: For that you place your listbox (assume it as a row of grid) and set the vertical alignment to bottom. Then the list will be growing upwards. And if you reverse the list of items before binding , you will get the desired effect.

Comment: Set the height of list box to auto. and the holding grid row should have a substantial height